# Passing Variables Into Xpath and Appending Strings Into List. Unable to Locate Element Error

Tags: python, list, selenium, webdriver

I'm trying to create a list using the inner HTML from elements from XML using Python, Selenium.

Here is a bit of my code:

```
count = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@id='ResultTable']//input[@class='ITIWebUICheckbox']")
numberinlist = len(count)
print(numberinlist)

masterlist = []

for n in range(numberinlist):
    labelslist = [0, 5, 7, 8]
    for j in labelslist:
        masterlist.append(driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            "//table[@id='ResultTable']//tr[contains(@id, 'ActivityDetails')][" + str(
                n) + "]//label[@class='ITIWebUILabel'][" + str(j) + "]").get_attribute('innerHTML'))

print(masterlist)
```

It counts the number of instances or rows I'm working with. Then uses the count for a range. That far I know lol. I'm now trying to add all strings of the inner HTML from xpath and append them to a list (masterlist). In the XML there is only one instance of "id='ResultTable'". There are finite (but usually more than 20) instances of id that contain the text 'ActivityDetails'. And for each id of 'ActivityDetails' there are 9 instances of label tag with 'class="ITIWebUILabel"'. I only need four of those instances, hence "[0, 5, 7, 8]". I'm trying to use those four elements, get their inner HTML, and put that HTML into a list but I am receiving the all-too-familiar "Unable to Locate Element" error for the xpath.

Here is a simplified sample of the XML that I am pulling from:

```
<table id="ResultTable"
    <tr id="ActivityDetails1"
        <label class="ITIWebUILabel" >05/01/2020</label>
        <label class="ITIWebUILabel" >Credit</label>
        .....etc.
    <tr id="ActivityDetails2"
        .....etc.
    <tr id="ActivityDetails3"
        ..........etc.
```

I'm a novice and self-taught with Python so I apologize in advance if the solution is obvious. Thanks!

Comment: Instead of trying to append a list with a different list, Can you please give this a try with enum?

Comment: @DeepBhatt I don't see how that would help. I'm not trying to find or use the numerical position of anything on either list...?

Comment: @JacobBaum try to increase your list to be `labelslist = [1, 6, 8, 9]` and `+ str(n)` to be `+ str((n+1))`

Comment: @frianH I already compensated for that. The numbers in those lists are adjusted for the way Python starts at the number zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for? This can be done without having to insert the indices into the XPaths. See if this works for you and let me know if you have any questions.

```
masterlist = []

# grab all of the table rows
for row in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@id='ResultTable']//tr[contains(@id,'ActivityDetails')]"):
    # grab the labels in the current row
    labels = row.find_elements_by_xpath(".//label[@class='ITIWebUILabel']")
    #                                    ^ notice the dot here... that tells the XPath to start with the 'row' element and search only descendants
    # get only the desired labels by index and store the innerHTML
    for index in [0, 5, 7, 8]:
        masterlist.append(labels[index].get_attribute('innerHTML'))
```

Comment: Thanks so much! A single dot  "." solved what I couldn't with  hours of trial and error.